# How to update ES6 Syntax for superset in array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of ES6 React code, which populates an array of MiniIcons onto a page.

```
const MiniIcons = ({miniicons}) => ( <div id="application"> {
      miniicons.map(miniicon => ( <MiniIcon key={minicon.id} id={miniicon.id} title={miniicon.name} handleOpenButton={this.handleMiniiconOpen.bind(this)} /> )
    )} </div> );
```

The JSON that populates "miniicons":

```
[
  {"id":"1", "name":"chicken", "application":"1"},
  {"id":"3", "name":"nuggets", "application":"1"},
  {"id":"8", "name":"fries", "application":"2"}
]
```

which makes a list like this:

```
<div id="application">
  <div class="minicion"></div>
  <div class="minicion"></div>
  <div class="minicion"></div>
</div>
```

However, some of those MiniIcons are part of a superset, application. I'm pretty new to this ES6 syntax, so how can I modify it so that a surrounding div can be created for each element where application is different, so for the above example:

```
<div id="application1">
  <div class="minicion"></div>
</div>
<div id="application2">
  <div class="minicion"></div>
  <div class="minicion"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to group the array by the application field, then map over the keys to create your `<div id="applicationN">` items, and a nested map over each value (which is an array of miniicons) to create your `<div class="miniicon">`. You can do the grouping using `reduce`, but a library like lodash would make it more convenient.

Comment: Yeah, here: `miniicons.reduce((groups, curr) => ({...groups, [curr.application]: [...(groups[curr.application] || []), curr]}), {})`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6 or (React-specific?) syntax, you just need a grouping algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Group you array using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) and then render them.

```
render() {
  const groupedIcons = _.groupBy(miniicons, 'application')
  return Object.keys(groupedIcons).map((applicationId) => {
    return (
      <div id={applicationId}>
        {groupedIcons[applicationId].map(miniicon => (
          <MiniIcon
            key={minicon.id}
            id={miniicon.id}
            title={miniicon.name}
            handleOpenButton={this.handleMiniiconOpen.bind(this)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Looks good, although can I still then map the Object.keys...etc to "const MiniIcons =" and reference with "<MiniIcons icons={miniicons} />" in react render method?

Comment: Yes you can. I changed the answer.

Comment: if I set  const Miniviews = ({reducedArry}) => { return Object.keys...etc with what you put, and then console.log(Miniviews), it actually returns the function as a type function, not the result of the function?

Comment: Firstly is this related to the question? Also when you do `const Miniviews = () => { .... }`. it declates Miniviews as function. To get output you need to call the function `const miniViewsArray = Miniviews()`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a start (vanilla ES6 no libs).

If I understand the problem, what you could do is create an object that contains arrays of "applications" grouped by the application property value.

```
{ 
  "1" : [ { application : 1, ... }, { application : 1, ... } ], 
  "2" : [ { application : 2, ...  } ] 
} ;
```

Once you've got that, you can see all you need to do is iterate that object.

Something like:

```
for ( let arr in top_level_obj ) {
   ...create div
   arr.forEach ( obj => { 
      ...add obj to div you just created
   }); 
}
```

(or however your framework goes about it)

Here's the code that creates the object of arrays:

```
let arr = [
  {"id":"1", "name":"chicken", "application":"1"},
  {"id":"3", "name":"nuggets", "application":"1"},
  {"id":"8", "name":"fries", "application":"2"}
];

let apps = {};
arr.forEach ( x => {
    if ( ! ( x.application in apps ) ) {
        apps [ x.application ] = [];
    }

    apps [ x.application ].push ( x );
} );

console.log ( apps );
```

From there it should be pretty easy to get what you want.

The application vals can be anything, numbers or whatever, they don't need to be in any order, etc.

Note you may want to make copies of the items you are rendering (otherwise they'll refer to the objects in the original array, which can be wonky depending on what you're doing), you'd do that like this:

```
apps [ x.application ].push ( Object.assign ( {}, x ) );
```